# Java Cannot implement a function in Map ADT interface that takes Pair class as its generic parameter

Tags: java, dictionary, generics, interface

I created a map interface that has the generic function `entries()`.

```
// return iterable collection of all the key-value entries in the map
public ArrayList<Pair<KeyType, ValueType>> entries();
```

The problem is, when I try to implement the interface I get this error in the interface file at the `entries()` function: `Bound mismatch: The type KeyType is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <KeyType extends Comparable<KeyType>> of the type Pair<KeyType,ValueType>`

My implementation of the function is shown below:

```
public ArrayList<Pair<KeyType, ValueType>> entries(){
    ArrayList<Pair<KeyType, ValueType>> list = new ArrayList<Pair<KeyType, ValueType>>();
    preorderList (root, list);
    return list;
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: please post the Map interface which you defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably left a generic bound out of the interface declaration.  Since your `Pair` requires keys to be comparable to each other (`KeyType extends Comparable<KeyType>`), your `Map` will need to reiterate this bound in its `KeyType` declaration in order to use `Pair` with its `KeyType`.  You may need to bound `ValueType` as well if `Pair` bounds it.

```
interface Map <KeyType extends Comparable<KeyType>, ValueType> { ... }
```

Under generic type erasure, `Pair`'s `KeyType` is replaced with `Comparable`.  If you do not bound `Map`'s `KeyType`, it is replaced with `Object`, which is not assignable to `Comparable` without a narrowing cast that can potentially fail.